# ionic 2 serve command error: Uncaught (in promise): [object PositionError]

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic2

Some times when serve command runs, this error appears and after several time it automatically goes away:

I have to mention that this error occurs only on map page which loads google map.

```
Uncaught (in promise): [object PositionError]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

its better if you show some code... but it seems that error generates from not being able to fulfill a promise `[object PositionError]` probably the app acts fine when testing on phone with `GPS` on to retrieve data

try to catch the error e.g.

```
 this.service(...).then(res => {}, err => {})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normally happens when getting geolocation in the browser. The reason is the browser don't support the plugin. You have to run this in a android phone or in an emulator.

P.S.:- if you see the message of the error, it should be "Timeout expired", meaning that no result came as they should be